# Nuspec file target absolute path

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I am writing a `.nuspec` file and a file must be copied to a specific absolute path when installing the package.

The snippet looks like this:

```
<files>
    <file src="myFolder\myFile.txt" target="C:\SomeFolder\myFolder" />
</files>
```

When I run `nuget pack`, I get the following error (this is `-Verbosity detailed`):

```
Target path 'C:\SomeFolder\myFolder' contains invalid characters.
```

System.Exception: Target path 'C:\SomeFolder\myFolder' contains invalid characters.
   at NuGet.Packaging.Manifest.Validate(Manifest manifest)
   at NuGet.Packaging.Manifest.ReadFrom(Stream stream, Func`2 propertyProvider, Boolean validateSchema)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder.ReadManifest(Stream stream, String basePath, Func`2 propertyProvider)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder..ctor(String path, String basePath, Func`2 propertyProvider, Boolean includeEmptyDirectories, Boolean deterministic)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.CreatePackageBuilderFromNuspec(String path)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromNuspec(String path)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)

I suppose this is related to the using the absolute path but

1) this used to work a year ago (I don't recall the exact version of nuget I had back then)

2) how do I specify an absolute path?

I am using the latest version of nuget, which I downloaded this morning.

Comment: Just saw the issue you opened on GitHub at https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9329. It seems you found a bug and the "We don't allow NuGet packages to have any files, than when extracted, affect files elsewhere on the disk. This is a security concern." doesn't quite hold (at least yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is by design, as they consider a security concern to have a nuget package that changes things outside the scope of the project where it gets installed. As answered in Github: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9329 (also as [Mihai Albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5853218/mihai-albert) mentioned in the comment)

A workaround I ended up using is packaging using relative paths and installing the package in the desired location.